# Elastic Search nested query string?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search 2 values in 2 different columns using wildcard but its not running as expected with 2 values but runs fine on single query_string

This works with single column

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
      "default_field" : "Phone",
      "query" : "*568072*"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to expand it to use it with 2 columns with 2 different values.

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "bool":
        {
            "should": [
                {
                    "query_string":
                    {
                        "query": "*Chicago*",
                        "fields": ["Sources"]
                    },
                    "query_string":
                    {
                        "query": "*493*",
                        "fields": ["Phone"]
                    }


                }


            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your query. You have one big object inside `should` array, that has two same keys that does not make sense. Instead it should be array of objects like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "query_string": { "query": "*Chicago*", "fields": ["Sources"] } },
        { "query_string": { "query": "*493*", "fields": ["Phone"] } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```